# Heroku: SSL Endpoint - subjectAltName does not match www.mydomain.com

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I have just been setting up my first app that requires ssl.

It's RoR app, hosted on Heroku.

I have added the SSL Endpoint add-on to my app.
I purchased a SSL certificate from DNSimple.

Then followed these instructions - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate
to concatenate the necessary files. Then uploaded them to my server.

So far so good.

Following these instructions - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#testing-your-certificate
for testing my certificat seems fine.

I have updated my DNS records with a CNAME that points to my Heroku generated Endpoint.

```
heroku certs
```

gives:

```
Endpoint                      Common Name(s)                          Expires               Trusted
----------------------------  --------------------------------------  --------------------  -------
<generated_id>.herokussl.com  www.mydomain.com, mydomain.com          2014-04-29 23:25 UTC  True
```

But when I try:

```
curl -v https://www.mydomain.com
```

I get:

```
* About to connect() to www.mydomain.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 107.20.162.205... connected
* Connected to www.mydomain.com (107.20.162.205) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Heroku, Inc.; CN=*.herokuapp.com
*    start date: 2011-04-11 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-04-15 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName does not match www.mydomain.com
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: maybe just a dns propagation delay? what's the actual domain in use?

Comment: @kch Thanks, I guess it was this as all working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the setup/config - There was a delay of about 24hrs, then everything worked as expected.